# Is it possible for a program cannot find the failure by using dynamic testing, but have fault?

Tags: testing, fault

Is it possible for a program cannot find the failure by using dynamic testing, but have fault? any simple example?

Please help! thanks.

Comment: Um... Huh? I don't know what you're asking and I'm fairly certain other people may have the same issue. Do you think you could clarify a little? :)

Comment: I believe this is the classic "how can I know if my software is bug-free" question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Testing can only prove the absence of bugs *for what you tested*. Dynamic testing cannot cover all possible inputs and outputs in all environments with all dependencies.

First is to simply not test the code in question. This can be verified by checking the [coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) of your test. Even if you achieve 100% coverage there can still be flaws.

Next is to not check all possible types and ranges of inputs. For example, if you have a function that scans for a word in a string, you need to check for...

- The word at the start of the string.
- The word at the end of the string.
- The word in the middle of the string.
- A string without the word.
- The empty string.

These are known as [boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_testing) and include things like:

- 0
- Negative numbers
- Empty strings
- Null
- Extremely large values
- Decimals
- Unicode
- Empty files
- Extremely large files

If the code in question keeps state, maybe in an object, maybe in global variables, you have to test that state does not become corrupted or interfere with subsequent runs.

If you're doing parallel processing you must test any number of possibilities for deadlocks or corruption resulting from trying to do the same thing at the same time. For example, two processes trying to write to the same file. Or two processes both waiting for a lock on the same resource. Do they lock only what they need? Do they give up their locks ASAP?

Once you test all the ways the code is supposed to work, you have to test all the ways that it can fail, whether it fails gracefully with an exception (instead of garbage), whether an error leaves it in a corrupted state, and so on. How does it handle resource failure, like failing to connect to a database? This becomes particularly important working with databases and files to ensure a failure doesn't leave things partially altered.

For example, if you're transferring money from one account to another you might write:

```
my $from_balance = get_balance($from);
my $to_balance   = get_balance($to);

set_balance($from, $from_balance - $amount);
set_balance($to,   $to_balance + $amount);
```

What happens if the program crashes after the first `set_balance`? What happens if another process changes either balance between `get_balance` and `set_balance`? These sorts of concurrency issues must be thought of and tested.

There's all the different environments the code could run in. Different operating systems. Different compilers. Different dependencies. Different databases. And all with different versions. All these have to be tested.

The test can simply be wrong. It can be a mistake in the test. It can be a mistake in the spec. Generally one tests the same code in different ways to avoid this problem.

The test can be right, the spec can be right, but the feature is wrong. It could be a bad design. It could be a bad idea. You can argue this isn't a "bug", but if the users don't like it, it needs to be fixed.

If your testing makes use of a lot of mocking, your mocks may not reflect how thing thing being mocked actually behaves.

And so on.

For all these flaws, dynamic testing remains the best we've got for testing more than a few dozen lines of code.